# jquery returning unexpected type for Kendo grid in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a kendo mvc grid in a .vbhtml view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Of RTFVM)(Model).Name("RealTimeFinancials") _
 .Columns(Sub(c)
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.LineItem).HtmlAttributes(New With {.style = "text-align:left"})
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.LineItem).HtmlAttributes(New With {.style = "text-align:left"})
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Months(0).Total).Format("{0:#,##0}")
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Months(1).Total).Format("{0:#,##0}")
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Months(2).Total).Format("{0:#,##0}")
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Months(3).Total).Format("{0:#,##0}")
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Months(4).Total).Format("{0:#,##0}")
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Months(5).Total).Format("{0:#,##0}")
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Months(6).Total).Format("{0:#,##0}")
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Months(7).Total).Format("{0:#,##0}")
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Months(8).Total).Format("{0:#,##0}")
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Months(9).Total).Format("{0:#,##0}")
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Months(10).Total).Format("{0:#,##0}")
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Months(11).Total).Format("{0:#,##0}")
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Total).Format("{0:#,##0}").HtmlAttributes(New With {.style = "text-align:right"})
          End Sub) _
.Editable(Function(editable) editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)) _
     .ToolBar(Sub(toolbar)
                      toolbar.Save()
              End Sub) _
                      .DataSource(Function(dataSource) dataSource _
                                      .Ajax() _
                                      .Batch(True) _
                                      .Model(Sub(m)
                                                     m.Id(Function(p) p.Line.LineItem)
                                                     m.Field(Function(p) p.Line.LineItem).Editable(False)
                                             End Sub) _
                                      .Read(Function(read) read.Action("BUReportRead", "RTF").Data("GetDDLYear()")) _
                                      .Update(Function(update) update.Action("Update", "RTF"))) _
                      .Editable(Function(editable) editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)))
```

I also have a DropDownList which is meant to refresh the grid upon a change:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("YearDropDownList") _
.DataTextField("YearText") _
.DataValueField("Year") _
.Events(function(x) x.Change("UpdateGrid()")) _
.DataSource(Function(source) source.Read(Function(read) read.Action("GetYears", "RTF"))) _
.SelectedIndex(0)
)
```

and a bit of javascript to handle the .change event:

```
 function UpdateGrid()
        {
            $(document).ready(function() 
            {
            var grid= $("#RealTimeFinancials").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.datasource.read();
            })
    }
```

The issue is that when debugging, the javascript variable 'grid' takes the type: 'i.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend.init' - and in the following line I get the error: 'Cannot read property 'read' of undefined'.

I'm sure this is something obvious...  I'd just expect var grid to be a kendoGrid with a read method (which it seems not to have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction on case-sensitive object property key `dataSource`,  "S" should be in capital-case

Change statement
from `grid.datasource.read();`

to...    `grid.dataSource.read();`

Comment: Thank you - now corrected - yes that did it... Need to watch my case-sensitivity!